# Cant logout from custom Admin Panel Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, admin, logout, laravel-5.7

I liked Matrix Admin panel, so i started implementing it. I didnt like the option of having admin in User model (boolean check isAdmin), so i created a separate model called Admin. I set up all the routes, and it worked in my test admin page with the following routes:

```
 web.php

Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')- 
 >name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')- 
 >name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.admin');

This is my AdminLoginController:
 public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin/admin-login');
}
protected function guard(){
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}

use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/admin/login';

 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

And my AdminController:
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('admin.admin');
}

I call routes in the view like this:
href="{{ route('admin.login') }}"

For some reason, it doesn't log me out and get me to the login page, instead it just refreshes the page, hence returns me to the /admin page with the admin logged in. What am i missing here? Thanks for all replies.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor for the `AdminLoginController`, you have set the middleware to be `'guest:admin'`.

This uses the guest middleware that is defined in `/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` by default, or configured in `/app/Http/Kernel.php`

The `$guard` string passed for it to use is `'admin'`.
I'm guessing that you provide an implementation for this *admin* guard.

Supposing that you're logged in as an admin, navigating to `route('admin.login')`
will [redirect your request to `'/home'`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.7.0/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21) in the default implementation; 
there are likely chances that there exists a custom redirection to `/admin` in your implementation.

If you like to logout of the session, you can register a route for the `logout` method provided in [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L153).

```
Route::get('/admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
```

Since the `AuthenticatesUsers::logout` redirects to `/` by default, I'm guessing you need to override this behavior. 
You can do exactly that by providing a custom implementation for `AuthenticatesUsers::loggedOut` in your controller.

```
protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Finally, provide this route for the *href* in your link `{{ route('admin.logout') }}`

Comment: Thank you Oluwafemi, i fixed it by adding this:

        $this->guard()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');

and then making loggedOut to redirect to the /admin/login path as i wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about session,

```
  \Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
```